# Why is process.stdout.write producing a 1 at the end

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have JavaScript code

```
process.stdout.write('Moe' + '\n');
process.stdout.write('Larry' + '\n');
process.stdout.write('Curly' + '\n');
```

The output on the end generates 'Curly1'. How do I remove? I tried using regex

```
process.stdout.write('Curly'.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') + '\n');
```

But still the output has 1 at the end.

Comment: I just copied your code into a script and ran it, there's no 1 output to my terminal. Is there other code in your script that could be causing this issue? I'm on v10.16.0 Linux.

Comment: Not getting any 1 here,.  Nodejs v.10.13.0, windows.